# RewriteRule URL RewriteRules http://www.example.com/login.php

Tags: .htaccess

I'm sure this is a rather silly question but I am having issues making it work.

I am trying to make a .htaccess RewriteRule to turn this URL...

```
http://www.example.com/login.php
```

to... `http://www.example.com/login/`

I have tried many different things to make this work with no success.

Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^login/?$ /login.php [L]
```

Then you need to make sure all of your links in your HTML content looks like `http://www.example.com/login/`. And make sure your links on the `login.php` page are absolute URLs, or include a

```
<base href="/" />
```

in the page's header.

Comment: Ahhhhh. I overlooked the "Options -Multiviews" option. Thank you very much!